# Update trigger causing SQL error "Cannot find the object "XXX" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."

Tags: sql-server

I am running into what seems to be a permission issue.

I have a database table that I created with a trigger that runs after a row update.  These are the commands I used to create the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[my_table_u]
ON [dbo].[my_table]
after UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
      SET nocount ON;
      UPDATE my_table
      SET
          last_updated_by = ( Host_name() + Suser_name() ),
          last_updated_dt = Getdate()
      FROM my_table
      INNER JOIN inserted ON my_table.id = inserted.id
  END
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[my_table] ENABLE TRIGGER [my_table_u]
GO
```

I am able to insert and delete rows from `my_table`, but whenever I go to update `my_table`, I get the following SQL error:

> Msg 1088, Level 16, State 13, Procedure my_table_u, Line 16
>   [Batch Start Line 0] Cannot find the object "my_table"
>   because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

However, if I drop and recreate the trigger *without the last ENABLE TRIGGER command*, like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[my_table_u]
ON [dbo].[my_table]
after UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
      SET nocount ON;
      UPDATE my_table
      SET
          last_updated_by = ( Host_name() + Suser_name() ),
          last_updated_dt = Getdate()
      FROM my_table
      INNER JOIN inserted ON my_table.id = inserted.id
  END
/*** NO ENABLE TRIGGER COMMAND HERE ***/
GO
```

Then I *am* able to update rows without error.

Would anyone have any ideas what is happening here?  Maybe some tips where I can start investigating?

Comment: You're trying to enable the trigger before its created, in fact its created enabled anyway, so you don't need to enable it. But if you did you would put a `GO` between the `END` and `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: @DaleK thanks for pointing that out.  Putting a a GO between the END and ALTER TABLE like you suggested did work (allowed me to update rows), but, I'm still curious what is *different* about the two that would make one behave different than the other.  Creating the trigger before the last GO still completes successfully, and still allows a super/admin user to update a row.  Any ideas there?

Comment: When making changes to the database structure from within a connection/session requires that you separate the commands so that one completes before you try and reference the new object. As I said though, you don't need to enable the trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The issue was that the `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[my_table] ENABLE TRIGGER [my_table_u]` line in the original CREATE TIGGER command *ended up being part of the update trigger*.  That is, whenever this trigger ran, it also tried to run `ALTER TABLE...ENABLE TRIGGER` as well, and my user didn't have ALTER permissions granted.

This was confirmed when I granted the user ALTER permissions on `my_table`, and the problem went away.

The "correct" solution, as pointed out by Dale K in the comments, is to leave out the ENABLE TRIGGER command completely, or, alternatively, make sure it comes *after* the GO statement that creates the trigger.

Comment: Same exact thing I had done. I didn't have a GO at the end of my trigger. THANKS!